# Apache webserver looking for internal address when accessed from internet

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I have installed Apache webserver on my Ubuntu 11.10, and have forwarded request to port 80 to my internal address. When accessing from local machines it all works very well, but when accessed from internet i can see that its looking for my internal ip from within the page im looking at. How come ? never encountered this problem before :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your HTML contains one or more explicit references to the internal IP-address. Probably.